# contents().find('html').html() doesn't set the body's style rules

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am experiencing a little problem with my code. The problem is, if I set the contents of an IFRAME using `contents().find('html').html()`, example, with this code snippet:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { background-color: red }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

the rules for body aren't applied, and the background color stays white (transparent). Does anybody know why that happnes?

Kind regards,
Peter.

Comment: maybe 'cause your snippet doesn't include any `<body>`?

Comment: I`m extremely sorry, I forgot to add it to this snippet. But with the body tag, it still doesn`t work.

Comment: The html content of the `<html>` element should not include the `<html></html>` part of the markup

Comment: Anything on the error console?

Comment: Do you see the new content of the iframe in your development tools? Is it correct there?

Comment: No, no errors in the console. Yes, I see the new content of the iFrame. The content of the iFrame is fetched from a textarea

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#myIframe").contents().find("body").css( "background-color", "red" );
```

where is your script, in parent document?